# Exception while validating username and password

Tags: java

I am creating a simple java application in form there is two text field for passing the username and password after the pressing the button it should its wrong or right user name and password. It gives the exception

> Exception caught

in execution query;

```
package myproject;

import java.sql.*;

public class connectionDB {

    String loadDriver = null;
    String url = null;
    String uName = null;
    String uPass = null;
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rst = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;

    public connectionDB() {
        loadDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase";
        uName = "root";
        uPass = "water";
    }

    void Connect() {
        try {
            try {
                Class.forName(loadDriver);
                System.out.println("Successfully load");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Fail to load");
            }
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uName, uPass);

            System.out.println("Connect to mysql sucessfull");
            st = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Something goes worng in Connection the mysql\n");

        }
    }

    boolean validateUserNamePassword(String uName, String uPass) {
        boolean isThere = false;
        int count = 0;
        try {


            pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from admin where "
                    + "Admin_Name= ? "
                   + "'and Admin_pass= ? ");


            pstmt.setString(1, uName);
            pstmt.setString(2, uPass);
            rst = pstmt.executeQuery();

            while (rst != null) {
                count = 1;
                isThere = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught in execution query");
        }
        if (isThere) {
            return isThere;
        } else {
            return isThere;
        }
    }

    void closeConnection() {
        try {
            st.close();
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Connection Sucessfully close with Database");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Excepiotn caught");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: this is the stacktrace of the error

> run: java.lang.NullPointerException else at myproject.connectionDB.validateUserNamePassword(connectionDB.java:48) at myproject.loginPage$Handler.actionPerformed(loginPage.java:96) at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018) at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341) at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402) at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259) at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252) at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505) at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321) at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270) at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861) at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422) at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273) at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723) at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76) at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696) at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97) BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: Print out the actual exception instead of the string that you hardcoded.

Comment: The code does not show how validateUserNamePassword is being called. For starters, I would like to put a null/blank check for username and password. in the validateUserNamePassword function.

Comment: @camickr its doesn't metter how to handle the exception ...... just i am checking in which excepition it goes wrong

Comment: *its doesn't metter how to handle the exception* yes it does. Usually, the error message tells you **the problem** and based on this you can seek **a solution** on an internet search. At least use `e.printStacktrace()`.

Comment: Yes it does matter, because the Exception message should give you more information about the problem. This is basic debugging. You should not display your own message unless it is your code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: @Manish i am just creating a class and calling that function in other class.... plz just check the code...

Comment: `plz just check the code...` - First of all its "please", and secondly if you want help then display the Exception otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  can u guyz plz check any thing wrong in prepareStatement function;

Comment: why do you have a while loop inside the try block? Maybe it's trying to run infinitely and throwing an `Exception`?

Comment: No matter how many times we check the code, the problem is inside the stacktrace that you don't want to see. It is like you put a black band in front of your eyes and code hoping to never get an exception and we can't help somebody that doesn't wanna help him/herself to begin with =\

Comment: So you have a NullPointerExceptin, now you can solve your problem. Figure out which variable is null and fix the problem. Since deleted your code for some reason I'm not sure how you expect us to help. Also, why did you post 20 lines, only the first couple of lines are required to tell you where the problem is. My guess is your text fields are null.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your query : Problem is with `'`. It should be like this :

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from admin where "
                + "Admin_Name= ? "
               + "and Admin_pass= ?");
```

Plus in your `validateUserNamePassword()` method :

```
if (isThere) {
        return isThere;
    } else {
        return isThere;
    }
}
```

This is not making any sense.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza at first, Exception was different. and user correct mistakes in code and update the question after my answer and now he/she is getting NPE.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but then it's OP's fault.

Answer (score -1):

you should enter the port number of mysql also

try this

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase";
```

`3306` is the default port number of mysql. If you have different port number then change it accordingly.

**Also** the way you are trying to retrieve will be an infinite loop

```
 while (rst != null) {
                count = 1;
                isThere = true;
            }
```

Use this way

```
 while (rst.next()) {
                count = 1;
                isThere = true;
            }
```

you have one`'` as **Vimal bera** has pointed out,change that accordingly

Comment: This is *not* a requirement. If no port is entered, 3306 is assumed by default.